# Leaflet usage in LitElement

Tags: javascript, leaflet, polymer, lit-element

I am currently working on an application using LitElement components. I would like to integrate Leaflet into it and am having issues with displaying the map. I have installed Leaflet in my project with npm and have created a class looking like this.

```
import {LitElement, html, css} from 'lit-element';
import './node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet';

class Map extends LitElement{

    static get styles() {
        return [css``];
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        let map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

        let urlTemplate = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
        map.addLayer(L.tileLayer(urlTemplate, {minZoom: 4}));
    }

    render() {
        return html`
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css">
            <div id="mapid" style="height: 100%"></div>

        `;
    }
}

customElements.define("my-map", Map);
```

Running my application results in following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'L' of undefined.
I am a little lost on how I could use Leaflet to display a map in my LitElement application and would be thankful for a nudge into the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for Lit projects we tend to suggest people stick to using the es-module imports (this is optional though). So instead of importing from

```js
import './node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet';
```

instead try:

```js
import {map as createMap, tileLayer} from './node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.esm.js';
```

This is because it usually fits in better with the modular nature of webcomponents as well as es modules can be optimized by bundlers much more effectively than calls to `window.L`

Next, rewrite your leaflet calls for this syntax. e.g.

```js
let map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

// should be
let map = createMap('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

// and
map.addLayer(L.tileLayer(urlTemplate, {minZoom: 4}))

// should be
map.addLayer(tileLayer(urlTemplate, {minZoom: 4}))
```

Next, libraries that require a global ID to function tend to have problems in web components that use shadow DOM as Shadow Roots scope DOM and thus queries to their roots. Though, luckily, [leaflet's documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-l-map) shows that we can instead pass it an element reference rather than just an id. This means we need to get the element reference like so:

```js
const mapEl = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#mapid');
```

which we can then pass into the `createMap` function

```js
const mapEl = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#mapid');
let map = createMap(mapEl).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
```

And finally we'll see that we run into the issue where the `mapEl` is `null`. The reason this is is because LitElement won't render it's contents until the [`firstUpdated` lifecycle callback](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/lifecycle#firstupdated). This means we have to change the location of map creation from `connectedCallback` to `firstUpdated`.

Here is a working example of your code in which I've also added a little bit of styling to give the custom element some height: https://jsbin.com/fumusodake/edit?html,output

Comment: Thank you so much for this helpful explanation. This worked like a charm!